# Trouble using time_t to check time of last modification in C

Tags: c, linux, time, compiler-errors

So I am having trouble implementing the mtime struct in C, where I am trying to check the last modification time of a file. When compiling, I receive this error:

`pr8.1.c:246: error: incompatible types when assigning to type struct timespec from type time_t
make: *** [pr8] Error 1`

The code I am using for this is as follows:

```
static struct timespec mtime(const char *file)
{
    struct stat s;
    struct timespec t = { 0, 0 };

    if (stat(file, &s) == 0)
#if     defined(MTIME) && MTIME == 1    // Linux
    { t = s.st_mtime; }
#elif   defined(MTIME) && MTIME == 2    // Mac OS X
    { t = s.st_mtimespec; }
#elif   defined(MTIME) && MTIME == 3    // Mac OS X, with some additional settings
    { t.tv_sec = s.st_mtime; t.tv_nsec = s.st_mtimensec; }
#else                                   // Solaris
    { t.tv_sec = s.st_mtime; }
#endif

    return t;
}
```

And the struct stat:

```
struct stat
{ time_t        st_mtime; };
```

P.S. sorry about the format, I am not sure why the format is acting like this. Running this with Linux. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: As a hint, take a look at what the other cases are doing and compare to the `struct stat` snippet you showed.  (One of them is already doing the right thing.)

Comment: I think I understand your point, however if I remove the `stuct stat` I get a compile time error that the storage size of "s" is not initialized, I figured I needed the `struct stat` for this reason?

Comment: No, you did not understand my point.  Consider what the other cases are doing, compared to the type of `st_mtime` you quoted.

Comment: I realize from the bottom response what you had meant now, thanks for the reply. I didn't think it was required for Linux and that version of Mac OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the linux and first mac os x version, you're assigning to the structure from an int (time_t).  In the other two versions, you are correctly assigning from a member of s to a member of t.  If you change to this, do you get correct operation?

```
static struct timespec mtime(const char *file)
{
    struct stat s;
    struct timespec t = { 0, 0 };

    if (stat(file, &s) == 0)
#if     defined(MTIME) && MTIME == 1    // Linux
    { t.tv_sec = s.st_mtime; }
//     ^^^^^^^ 
#elif   defined(MTIME) && MTIME == 2    // Mac OS X
    { t.tv_sec = s.st_mtimespec; }
//     ^^^^^^^ 
#elif   defined(MTIME) && MTIME == 3    // Mac OS X, with some additional settings
    { t.tv_sec = s.st_mtime; t.tv_nsec = s.st_mtimensec; }
#else                                   // Solaris
    { t.tv_sec = s.st_mtime; }
#endif

    return t;
}
```

Comment: I do thank you, although I'm not sure I quite understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler told you the types are incompatible, and they obviously are.